# Swift scrollToRow then highlight that row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What I would like to do is scrollToRow, then animate the background of that row so it's background changes visibly, so the user can see that exact row.

I have a table with ~100 rows, and when scrollToRow is triggered, it scrolls to the right row, but it gets lost in the other rows. I just want the user to have the ability to spot that row more easily...

Comment: Instead of scrolling you can use `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrow

Comment: @Rishab question updated, that does help me get closer to my necessary solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, any of following solutions, all them works fine:

#### [scrollToRow(at:at:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow)

Scrolls through the table view until a row identified by index path is at a particular location on the screen.

```
func scrollToRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, at scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

#### [scrollToNearestSelectedRow(at:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614910-scrolltonearestselectedrow)

Scrolls the table view so that the selected row nearest to a specified position in the table view is at that position.

```
func scrollToNearestSelectedRow(at scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

#### [scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible)

Scrolls a specific area of the content so that it is visible in the receiver. Use scrollview of tableview to achieve this result

```
func scrollRectToVisible(_ rect: CGRect, animated: Bool)
```

#### [selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrow)

Selects a row in the table view identified by index path, optionally scrolling the row to a location in the table view.

```
func selectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition)
```